# Oozie Pig action stuck in PREP state and job is in RUNNING state

Tags: hadoop, workflow, apache-pig, oozie

I want to run a simple workflow but it gets stuck in PREP state every time i submit the job. Here i am trying to read the values from text file which are comma separated and print them on screen. Fot this i am using following properties file, workflow file and script file.

Environment:
Hadoop: 2.6.0 (1 namenode and 2 datanode)
Oozie : 4.1.0
Pig   : 0.14.0

This is my Properties File:
 `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>nameNode</name>
        <value>hdfs://<IP/aliasname>:<port></value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>jobTracker</name>
        <value><IP/aliasname>:<port></value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>oozie.libpath</name>
        <value><path/to/pig/jars></value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>
        <value><path/to/workflow app/in hdfs></value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

`

This is my Workflow:

```
    <workflow-app name="samplewrokflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to="TestJob"/> 
    <action name="TestJobR">
        <pig>
            <job-tracker><IP/alias name>:<port></job-tracker>
            <name-node>hdfs://<IP/alias name>:<port></name-node>
            <script><Path/to/pig/script></script>
        </pig>
         <ok to="success"/> 
            <error to="fail"/>  
   </action>
  <kill name="fail"> 
       <message>The Identity Map-Reduce job failed!</message> 
   </kill>
  <end name="success"/>
</workflow-app>
```

This is my Pig script:

```
DATA = LOAD 'path/to/sample.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (name1:chararray,name2:chararray,number:int);DUMP DATA;
```

This is my content in sample.txt:
abc,xyz,1

Command used to run the job:

```
oozie job --oozie http://<IP address>:<port>/oozie -config <path/to/configuration file> -run
```

After running this command i get the job Id from screen.

This is my oozie job logs:

```
2015-06-08 10:58:56,814  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[pal-hadoop1.cloudapp.net] USER[hadoop1] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlow_R] JOB[0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]

2015-06-08 10:58:56,815  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[pal-hadoop1.cloudapp.net] USER[hadoop1] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlow_R] JOB[0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE

2015-06-08 10:58:56,815  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[pal-hadoop1.cloudapp.net] USER[hadoop1] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlow_R] JOB[0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000026-150603135220320-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
```

When i get the info using job Id it shows that the job is in PREP state always.

I executed the script independently using pig and it worked fine.

My workflow directory in hdfs structure:

```
oozie-wf/pigscript.pig   
oozie-wf/workflow.xml  
oozie-wf/sample.txt  
oozie-wf/lib (Contains all pig jar files)
```

Can you tell me what would be the possible issue here because i could not rectify it from my side? and let me know if you require more details.

Comment: I assume `<start to="TestJob"/> ` should be `<start to="TestJobR"/> ` ?

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the finding.. But after making correction as you said from  TESTJob to TestJobR, i am still facing same issue.

Comment: are you specifying all path as absolute paths? are you sure that the addresses/ports for namenode and jobtracker are correct?

Comment: how many map slots does your MapReduce cluster have?

Comment: @ Fred - Yes! I am specifying all paths as absolute paths. Please consider the following: **oozie libpath :** /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150505120506/pig   **workflow path:** /user/wf/oozie-wf/Workflow_R.xml   **script path:** /user/wf/oozie-wf/Pigscript_R.pig     **jobtracker:** ip address where job tracker is running and port

Comment: @Fred and Mikhail - Guys, The job is moved from PREP state to RUNNIG state. actually the issue was relied on the job tracker port. The port was not open on server where the job tracker was running. Thanks guys for your valuable contribution for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of low number of containers on the cluster. How many containers do you have on yarn? Simply said, one container occupied for oozie, rest are needed to run the job. Probably pig might also be holding one container, though i am not sure about that. In case the containers are not sufficient for executing the job, it will remain stuck in PREP state.

Comment: Is yarn-site.xml holds the property which gives the information about the no. of container, if yes then could you please revert with the name of property to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of Total Memory of nodemanager (or) reduce the container default size using following properties at yarn-site.xml

```
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>12288</value>
  </property>

 <property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>2048</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>6144</value>
  </property>
```

if your case is having low container slots!! use the above fix!! or else find the oozie log or yarn log what its states.

Comment: i newbie to this so i will be showing you the property values from my yarn-site.xml. Here are,

Comment: @ karthik - i am newbie to this so i do not have much idea about the configuration parameters so i am showing you the property values from my yarn-site.xml. Here are, **yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 12288, yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 2048, yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 12288**.  Can this property values shows that the cluster is having low container slots?

Comment: Pls set the configuration as 
       <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
   <value>12288</value>
   </property>
  
   <property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
   <value>2048</value>
   </property>
   <property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
   <value>6144</value>
   </property>
and try it!!! Answer was edited as per you config just replace and try.